# Safari stays in hover state CSS bug

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover

I have a CSS dropdown menu. It works properly with Firefox, Chrome, IE7+, but not Safari. Weird. The drop down menu stay in the :hover state if you are in the parent menu.

I can quite describe this right, but basically the dropdown menu works fine on any page, except when the parent item is selected.

Works fine: http://firstglancesolutions.kinetixbizsuite.com/
Doesn't work: http://firstglancesolutions.kinetixbizsuite.com/services

Seems weird that the added class should mess up only Safari? I've been trying to find bugs or any related issues with just Safari, but can't seem to debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the Home and Services pages each use different methods of revealing the dropdown. The Home page changes the `display` of the dropdown `UL`. The Services page changes the `overflow` of the dropdown's parent `LI`, which seems to cause problems in Safari. I suggest using the Home page method on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

The same JavaScript `/CatalystScripts/Java_DynMenusSelectedCSS.js` is being referenced five times throughout the page.

Try reducing it to only one and see if that helps.

Comment: yeah, that's all business catalyst being weird. It's adding it per dynamic menu.

Answer (score 0):

You are also using jQuery (line 14-18) but not including the jquery js file.